# How do I pass a -fpermissive parameter to the compiler in a ./build_native.sh file?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Alright, please don't kill me.

I know this is a bad coding practice, but I'm just trying to grasp the fundamentals of an API, and there are only outdated tutorials about this, so where does it go in this file?

```
APPNAME="samplecocos2dxandroid"
NDK_ROOT="/Users/n/Documents/android-ndk-r8d"

# options

buildexternalsfromsource=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ code for $APPNAME using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
-s  Build externals from source
-h  this help
EOF
}

while getopts "sh" OPTION; do
case "$OPTION" in
s)
buildexternalsfromsource=1
;;
h)
usage
exit 0
;;
esac
done

# paths

if [ -z "${NDK_ROOT+aaa}" ];then
echo "please define NDK_ROOT"
exit 1
fi

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
# ... use paths relative to current directory
COCOS2DX_ROOT="$DIR/../.."
APP_ROOT="$DIR/.."
APP_ANDROID_ROOT="$DIR"

echo "NDK_ROOT = $NDK_ROOT"
echo "COCOS2DX_ROOT = $COCOS2DX_ROOT"
echo "APP_ROOT = $APP_ROOT"
echo "APP_ANDROID_ROOT = $APP_ANDROID_ROOT"

# make sure assets is exist
if [ -d "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets ]; then
    rm -rf "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

mkdir "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets

# copy resources
for file in "$APP_ROOT"/Resources/*
do
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    cp -rf "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi
done

# copy icons (if they exist)
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-72.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
fi
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-48.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
fi
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-32.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
fi


if [[ "$buildexternalsfromsource" ]]; then
    echo "Building external dependencies from source"
    "$NDK_ROOT"/ndk-build -C "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT" $* \
        "NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source"
else
    echo "Using prebuilt externals"
    "$NDK_ROOT"/ndk-build -C "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT" $* \
        "NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt"
fi
```

Tested this solution but failed, is this how it's suppose to be done?

In android-ndk-r8b/build/core/default-build-commands.mk:

```
TARGET_CC       = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)gcc
TARGET_CFLAGS   = 

TARGET_CXX      = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)g++
TARGET_CXXFLAGS = $(TARGET_CFLAGS) -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpermissive

TARGET_LD       = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ld
TARGET_LDFLAGS :=

TARGET_AR       = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ar
TARGET_ARFLAGS := crs

TARGET_STRIP    = $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)strip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-fpermissive would go as one of the compiler flags, which this script (itself) does not do. It only packages the assets and such.

It would go into here: android-ndk-r8b/build/core/default-build-commands.mk

Keep in mind, that this change will affect all builds. Though, it sounds like that is what you want.

Comment: I've tested a solution with your advise, can you help me verify if what I've done is correct? Thanks!

Comment: seems like it, unless you're compiling .c files (then you would need to add it to the TARGET_CFLAGS). The way to check is do your build command like this: "ndk-build V=1", and then examine the verbose output and look for your flag. If everything went according to plan you should see it there